# Is Ubuntu Phone OS going to include tools for development within the mobile platform?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I saw examples od native QML and HTML5 applications ,but Ubuntu is not Linux if one can't develop on it LOCALLY. Will Ubuntu Phone contain `gcc`, `qmake`, a python shell or similar tools?

Comment: ubuntu is Linux. the worlds most popular distro, why are you saying its not.
but about the build-in compilers... i don't think so.

Comment: There will be an SDK, right now it's too early.

Answer (score 5):

Let's take our Ubuntu Touch Developer Preview.

I can ssh to a shell. 
My Tablet is connected wirelessly to the internet.

So I can add development tools:

```
phablet@localhost: sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

then create a new file hello.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(void) {
  printf("hello world!\n");
}
```

Now I can compile my C program:

```
phablet@localhost: gcc hello.c
```

and I can run it:

```
phablet@localhost: ./a.out
```

the output is:

```
hello world!
```

Conclusion: It is a real linux. It has already it's basic tools available. 
And they work!

And I don't think that in the future anybody will try to find a way to remove the opportunity to install and run these essential development tools.

Even if there will be an Ubuntu Phone in the future where these tools are not included by default it will always be possible to add them in a very simple way.

I love this new world!

Comment: And think about this: How easy can you do this on: IPhone/IPad, WP8, BB, Android (ok that's rather possible, maybe)

Comment: Note on an E5 Ubuntu Edition device: "`sudo apt-cache search build-essential`" returns nothing (although `gcc-4.9-base` is there, but no `gcc-4.9`); also [Installing packages by apt-get is not possible because Ubuntu touch devices have a readonly filesystem by default.. It can be disabled through USB ...](http://askubuntu.com/questions/689122/install-gcc-g-on-ubuntu-phone) ... so I guess it can be different